# No aparece el texto de la pagina en page.php

Tags: wordpress

Buenas,

Tengo el siguiente código en page.php

```
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?>


<section class="cuadricula_equipo">
  <div class="cuadricula_fotos">
    <div class="foto_1"></div>
    <div class="foto_2"></div>
    <div class="foto_3"></div>
    <div class="foto_4"></div>
  </div>

  <article class="equipo_descripcion">
   <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

En el backooffice, tengo una pagina que se llama equipo y dentro una descripción. El problema que tengo, que las imágenes las veo pero a través del template tag the_content no lo veo.

¿Es posible que the_content solo sea para entradas y no valga para paginas? ¿cual sería para paginas en caso de estar errónea?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) trabaja en el loop de Wordpress. Es decir:

```
<section class="cuadricula_equipo">
  <div class="cuadricula_fotos">
    <div class="foto_1"></div>
    <div class="foto_2"></div>
    <div class="foto_3"></div>
    <div class="foto_4"></div>
  </div>

  <article class="equipo_descripcion">

  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div>
        <?php the_content(); ?> 
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  </article>
</section>
```

---

En algunos casos, si lo quieres usar fuera del loop, puedes hacer:

```
echo $post->post_content;
```

Esta opción no estoy seguro que funcione en las páginas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!